# Velocity of a point in 3D after elastic collision with infinite mass wall, given only normal to wall, mass and velocity of point

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

I am writing a program where I would need to program the following.

A point is moving in the *3d* space with velocity *(DX, DY, DZ)* towards an arbitrary plane.

The "plane" represents an "obstacle" that cannot move (say of infinite mass). I only have the normal
vector to the plane, say *(N1, N2, N3)*.

Assuming the point to have a rest mass *m* constant, and the collision to happen and be elastic, I would like to compute the updated *(DX, DY, DZ)* of the point bouncing **after the collision**.

Can you put me in the right direction to compute these updated velocities
in the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the wall has infinite mass, the point particle will reflect off the wall with the same speed and a direction that follows the reflection laws.  The reflection matrix given the unit normal vector to the plane $\mathbf{n} = (n_x, n_y, n_z) $ is given by

$  \mathbf{ R = (I - 2 n n^T ) }$

Therefore, the final velocity of the point mass is

$ \mathbf{v_2 = R v_1} $

Comment: wow! beautiful indeed! I did not expect it could come up so elegant and neat!  :-) I am looking forward to trying it!  Thanks a lot for your precious help!